# Crysis2 complains of Strict NAT and cannot find session

Tags: technical-issues, crysis-2

There's loads about this online, but I've followed all the advice I've found so far.

- My machine is on a static local IP.
- I've opened all the ports in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\crysis 2\Support\readme.txt` through my router.
- I've set Norton Antivirus to `Allow` for `Crysis2.exe`.

My symptoms are as such:

- I can never find a session. Ever.
- Every time I try to log in it re-awards me my preorder bonuses.
- Every time I log in it resets my unlocks and I get to choose what to spend my points on.

I can surmise that I'm getting inbound traffic from their server but not sending outbound traffic to let them update my account. I have no idea what not being able to find a session means.

The most perplexing thing is that I could play the Demo fine without setting anything up...

Comment: It is strange that the demo works and the full game does not, but then again networks run on magic.  Try enabling UPnP on your router if it isn't already.  Make sure you are forwarding both TCP and UDP ports.  You could also try setting up port triggering instead of just port forwarding.  Additionally, sometimes its as simple as a good old hard reset of your network hardware.  It helps get the magic flowing.

Comment: Even tried using my computer as a DMZ with no firewall (very breifly). an extended googling session later suggests it might be my router model, the O2 Wireless Router IV, and that the only solution is to get a new adsl2plus router. If this turns out to be true (need to buy a new router to test) then I'll answer/close this question... Any other suggestions in the meantime would be welcome...